# Как разместить custom view в лайауте?

Tags: java, android, customview

Я делаю приложение с EditText'ом куда можно написать ссылку на изображение, с кастомным View для отображения изображения и с кнопкой для обновления View. Когда я пытаюсь его вставить в лайаут он выдает ошибку:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.alex9127.urlimageloader, PID: 11361
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.alex9127.urlimageloader/ru.alex9127.urlimageloader.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21 in ru.alex9127.urlimageloader:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #21 in ru.alex9127.urlimageloader:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class ru.alex9127.urlimageloader.DrawView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21 in ru.alex9127.urlimageloader:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #21 in ru.alex9127.urlimageloader:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class ru.alex9127.urlimageloader.DrawView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21 in ru.alex9127.urlimageloader:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class ru.alex9127.urlimageloader.DrawView
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ru.alex9127.urlimageloader.DrawView.<init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:822)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at ru.alex9127.urlimageloader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Почему оно выскакивает, если я указываю класс в лайауте?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/url"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:hint="@string/editTextHint"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:autofillHints="false"
        android:inputType="textUri"/>

    <view
        class="ru.alex9127.urlimageloader.DrawView"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/url"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view"
        android:onClick="invalid"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по логу ошибки

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ru.alex9127.urlimageloader.DrawView.<init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
```

в вашем классе не хватает конструктора с указанными параметрами, а именно

```
public DrawView(android.content.Context context, interface android.util.AttributeSet attr) {

}
```

Comment: а как аттрибуты применить?

Comment: Вы про параметры конструктора? Если вы не передаёте из разметки что то то можно их и не трогать

Comment: понятно, теперь я не понимаю что он выдает Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.postInvalidate()' on a null object reference

Comment: Задайте под эту проблему новый вопрос, приложив в него код вашей вьюхи и однозначное точное указание строки, на которой оно падает. Одна проблема - один вопрос